# How to setup a wired local area network in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, thinkpad

I am using a Lenovo ThinkPad X200 and want to setup a wired local area network.

How could I achieve this?

**Situation:**

I just want to connect to the internet and I have a cable connection at home.

So, I just want to plug the cable line to my notebook (x200) so that I can access the internet via the cable.

But I don't know how to setup a local area connection in notebook. Since it automatically appear in my desktop, but not in my notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is a little unclear, so i'll talk about 2 possible scenarios.

First, you want to use the x200 as a router. You'd need at LEAST two ethernet ports (so you'd want to add one with a PCMCIA or Express card), connect one to a modem, one to a hub or whatever you want to connect. Run internet connection sharing to share the network

The second, you want to use it as a client. Connect one end of a cable to a modem or router the other to your computer. Everything should take care of itself.

If you have something else in mind, add it to your question and i'll edit my answer to suit.

Comment: I just want to connect to the internet and I have a cable connection at home.

So, I just want to plug the cable line to my notebook (x200) so that I can access the internet via the cable.

But I dont know how to setup a local area connection in notebook. Since it automatically appear in my desktop, but not in my notebook.